# IIS 7.5 AppDomain recycle causing losing session after adding virtual directory to 'Default Web site'

Tags: iis-7.5, application-pools, virtual-directory

I hope you can help me out here, because i tried to get some answers already in another board ([see here](http://forums.iis.net/p/1182364/1999133.aspx#1999133)) This Question is build on a reply of Scott Forsyth [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/315652/iis7-5-prevent-recycling-when-changing-default-document/371909#371909).

When adding a new virtual directory to the 'default web site' in IIS Manager, all the other Applications located in the default web site are recycled somehow. In order to simplify my problem, i took an example where i could track a timestamp from an current session and realized that the session information is really getting lost after adding a VD, meaning the AppDomain was recycled.

This is the situation:

Sites

```
Default Web Site

    1 (virtual directory) (d:\TestAppDomains\1\)

       - app1 (Application)           (using App Pool 1)

    2 (virtual directory) (d:\TestAppDomains\2\)

       - app2 (Application)           (using App Pool 2)
```

As far as i understood adding a virtual directory is just making changes to the applicationHost.config, which should not cause the AppDomains to recycle. Maybe it is a delegation issue, but i guess i dont get it enough to understand :(

Are there any properties which affect this behaviour? I´ve already set the AppPool settings to not recylcing after a configuration change, but it didnt help.

I would REALLY appreciate if you could help me out with this one, because i am struggling with it for almost 6 months now.

Of course i´ll gladly provide more information if you need them.

**Update 1:**

The HealthMonitoring cannot help me out on this one for two reasons:

1. Cannot find any entry for AppPool recycle, where should it be? Event Viewer -> Windows Logs / Application and Services Logs? (Should be configured properly)
2. Maybe i got something wrong. First i thought it is an app-pool recycle but with the simplified test i build an example without any applications and additional app-pools. Now it just looks like this:

Sites

```
Default Web Site

    1 (virtual directory) (d:\TestAppDomains\1\)          
           session1.aspx (Sets current timestamp to session variable and redirects to session2.aspx)
           session2.aspx (displays session variable)
```

By calling the localhost/1/sessions1.aspx i can see the timestamp. After adding a second virtual directory (e.g. "2" (d:\TestAppDomains\2)) and refreshing the page the session is gone, meaning the variable is null.

Cheers, Adam

Comment: Perhaps you should distinguish between your application pool recycling and your application domain restarting.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same situation as you described at [IIS forum](http://forums.iis.net/p/1182364/1999133.aspx#1999133): one web site, several application pools, several pairs of Applications (web-service) and Virtual directories (html + js), automated deployment and so on.
The problem was the same: when I added/removed virtual directory, all applications restarted. This was not good as I planned to serve multiple versions and wanted users to work while fresh version was deployed.
I've played with settings delegation with no success. Then I noticed that adding/removing of one Application didn't led to the restart of others. 
So, this was the solution: **create for web pages separate Application instead of Virtual directory**.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an ASP.NET *application domain* restarting, the reasons are covered thoroughly here:

https://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2006/08/02/asp-net-case-study-lost-session-variables-and-appdomain-recycles.asp

Do you have *application pool* recycling event logging enabled?  That would be the first place I would start:

[image]

If you have an ASP.NET application, you can also enable HealthMonitoring in the system.web section of web.config.  These logging options may be helpful in identifying what is occurring.  A sample:

```
  <system.web>
    <healthMonitoring enabled="true" heartbeatInterval="1">    
      <rules>
        <add name="HeartBeat" 
             eventName="Heartbeats" 
             provider="EventLogProvider" 
             profile="Default" 
             minInstances="1"
             minInterval="00:01:00"
             maxLimit="Infinite"/>
        <add name="App Lifetime"
             eventName="Application Lifetime Events"
             provider="EventLogProvider"
             profile="Default"
             minInstances="1" 
             minInterval="00:00:00"
             maxLimit="Infinite"/>
      </rules>
    </healthMonitoring>
```

FAQ - Health Monitoring in ASP.NET 2.0
http://forums.asp.net/t/1027461.aspx/1

healthMonitoring Element (ASP.NET Settings Schema)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2fwh2ss9%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks Greg, i have updated my initial question for more information.